# Update each row in a table with existing values but capitalized

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I have a table that has the following structure

```
LanguageName    |Code 
----------------|----
Abkhaz          |ab
Afar            |aa
Afrikaans       |af
Akan            |ak
```

I have about 190 similar rows.

And,

> I need to update each row as Capitalizing the first letter of the
>   Column Code for each row.

So, that the result would be:

```
LanguageName    |Code 
----------------|----
Abkhaz          |Ab
Afar            |Aa
Afrikaans       |Af
Akan            |Ak
```

How can I achieve this in SQL-Server?

Answer (score 2):

```
update your_table
set Code = UPPER(substring(code, 1, 1)) + substring(code, 2, 1)
```

### edit

single steps:

```
substring(code, 1, 1)   -> extracts the 1st character from code column
substring(code, 2, 1)   -> extracts the 2nd character from code column
UPPER()                 -> uppers the 1st substring
substring1 + substring2 -> puts them together
set code =              -> the result of the above for every row
```

Comment: Great Answer. First, I thought Update 'table' Set Column='columnValue'+'-' like statement would update the whole table with similar values, but when I applied it works absolutely fine. Can you explain how? because if we write something like Update 'table' Set Column='anyvalue', it would update the whole table to 'anyvalue'

Comment: By the way: If you want to provide examples for your SQL queries you can use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score 1):

```
update YourTable set
  LanguageName = stuff(LanguageName, 1, 1, upper(left(LanguageName,1))),
  Code = stuff(Code, 1, 1, upper(left(Code,1)))
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75099)

Comment: Excellent! Clarifying in StackDataExplorer is Super Cool!